# Unknown App Icons in OS X’s Launchpad

Tags: macos

In Mac OS X Lion, I have some good number of Unknown Apps listed in launchpad. I am not sure how they got installed/placed out there.

Can anyone help me remove these icons? I tried searching these files in Finder, but I’m unable to find them.

[image: Image showing Launchpad icons]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting your launchpad by writing following into terminal window

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ; killall Dock
```

This will reset your launchpad and you will loose any customizations you did (if any)...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will I be able to see my default icons after this (I mean app icons that are available in Applications Folder)? If not, how can I bring them back?

I don't want to loose the default app icon list in Launchpad.

Comment: when I tried, I'd seen my default icons in my applications folder... you should try...